# Given a set of 3 2D points, how to find if they lie within a circle of a given radius?

Tags: geometry

Given 3 points, A (x1, y1), B (x2, y2) and C (x3, y3), what is the best way to tell if all 3 points lie within a circle of a given radius **r**?

The best I could come up with was to find the Fermat point F (x4, y4) for the triangle ABC, and then check if the distance from F to each A, B and C is less than **r**. Is there a way to do this more efficiently?

Comment: Well, all three points are on the point of exactly one circle.  Figure out the circle and *see* if it has radius r.

Comment: What if one point of the Fermat point is less than r and another is larger.  then it tells you nothing.

Comment: Just to iterate on a few of the comments: you are correct, the circumcenter is not the right point to place the center of the circle on. There may exist a smaller r within which all of the 3 points can fit than the circumradius.

Comment: @fleablood: I was thinking that if all 3 distances (AF, BF, CF) are less than r, then the points lie within a circle of radius r. If any of the distances AF, BF, or CF is greater than r, then A, B and C do NOT lie within a circle of radius r.

Comment: That doesn't work for a long and skinny needle-shaped triangle.

Comment: Why not? Do you have an example triangle where it wouldn't work?

Comment: A needle-shaped triangle of height just under $2r$ fits in a circle of radius $r$. But its Fermat point is very close to the short edge, so the distance from the Fermat point to the far vertex is nearly $2r$ and your test fails.

Comment: Yes, you are right - the Fermat point won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smallest enclosing circle for three points is either the circumcircle of the triangle formed by the points (if the triangle is acute) or the circle whose diameter is the longest edge of the triangle (if the triangle is obtuse). The two circles coincide if the triangle is right-angled. There exists a circle of radius $r$ that encloses the points if and only if the radius of the smallest enclosing circle is less than or equal to $r$.

Comment: Thank you Rahul, I think this is the right answer, and in the case or a right-angled triangle, also poetically beautiful :)

Answer (score 1):

Welp, Rahul in a comment took the wind out of my sail.  Rather seriously.

Okay.  Measure the three distances.  Find the two that are furthest apart.  If that is more than $2r$ they are not in a circle.  If they are less than $2r$ apart, find the two points that are exactly $r$ away from both points.  Find two circles centered at the points with radius $r$.  If the third point is in either circle we are done.  All three points are within that circle.  If not, we are still done.  If the three points aren't within either of those circles they won't be within any other circles either.

===

Take the perpendicular bisector of two pairs of points.  The intersection will be equal distance from all three.  (The three points will lie on a circle with that distance as a radius and that point of intersection as the center.)  If the distance if less than $r$ then the points are interior to such a circle.  Otherwise not.

Comment: The points $(-1,0),(0,0.1),(0,1)$ lie within a circle of radius $1$, but their circumradius is very large. You also want to check if the two farthest points form the diameter of a circle containing the third point.

Comment: Hmm, good point.

Comment: I think that this would be the circumcenter point, which does give us a circle of radius r where all points do fit in, but again, this is not guaranteed to be the minimum r of any circle that fits these points, and we need the minimum r.

Comment: Minimum r was not part of the question.  The question asked was a *given* r.  You can't complain about a question not answering a question that was not asked.

Comment: Actually, finding the "minimum r" is exactly what this question reduces to. To be able to answer for "any r", we need to find the "minimum r" first.

Comment: If that was your freaking question you should have *asked* that.  The question you asked was "what is the best way to tell if all 3 points lie within a circle ***of a given*** radius r".  Well, the best way to tell that is to measure the dang things.  If the two furthest points are more than 2r apart they aren't.  If they are less then its a matter of showing third is within one r of a mutual point.